# Trying to make a counter in a global object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a counter for different types of coffee. Whenever they click on a coffee, the counter should go up once in the object. (see function handleClickButton) Even though I have a console.log reading the val.counter, It doesn't show in the console. When I try to console.log the object at the end of the forEach, the counter still stays at 0.

I tried console.log(Object.entries(orders)); to see what it puts out, and I get nested Arrays. But when I do console.log(val) (the one inside the forEach), I get each individual Object from the object orders.

```
import data from './assets/data/coffees.json';

const orders = {
  oatLatte: {counter: 0, id: 1},
  soyLatte: {counter: 0, id: 2},
  riceLatte: {counter: 0, id: 3},
  kokoLatte: {counter: 0, id: 4},
  almondLatte: {counter: 0, id: 5},
  pumpkinSpice: {counter: 0, id: 6},
  saltedCaramel: {counter: 0, id: 7},
  toastedGraham: {counter: 0, id: 8}
};

const init = () => {
  console.log(data);
  createPriceList(data);
};

const createPriceList = coffees => {
  const ul = document.querySelector('.prices__list');
  console.log(coffees);

  coffees.coffees.forEach(coffee => {
    if (coffee.plantbased === true) {
      const li = document.querySelector('.price');
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.classList.add('price__button');
      const spanWrapper = document.createElement('span');
      spanWrapper.classList.add('price__button__wrapper');
      const spanName = document.createElement('span');
      spanName.classList.add('price__button__name');
      const spanAmount = document.createElement('span');
      spanAmount.classList.add('price__button__amount');
      const spanPlus = document.createElement('span');
      spanPlus.classList.add('price__button__plus');
      spanPlus.setAttribute('id', coffee.id);
      spanName.textContent = coffee.name;
      spanAmount.textContent = '\u20AC';
      const price = coffee.prices.medium;
      const newPrice = price.toFixed(2); //add 2 decimals
      const finalPrice = newPrice.replace('.', ','); //replace . with ,
      spanAmount.textContent += finalPrice;
      spanPlus.textContent = '+';

      ul.appendChild(li);
      li.appendChild(a);
      a.appendChild(spanWrapper);
      spanWrapper.appendChild(spanName);
      spanWrapper.appendChild(spanAmount);
      a.appendChild(spanPlus);

      spanPlus.addEventListener('click', handleClickButton);

    }
  });
};


const handleClickButton = e => {
  document.querySelector('.emptystate').style.display = 'none';
  console.log(e.target.id);
  Object.entries(orders).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    console.log(val);
    if (e.target.id === val.id) {
      val.counter ++;
      console.log(val.counter);
    }
  });
  console.log(Object.entries(orders));
};


init();
```

My question is why is the counter not going up, and why is it not showing in the console?

Comment: "Even though I have a console.log reading the val.counter, It doesn't show in the console", i think this is a pretty good hint towards what's happening.

Comment: Do you see the output from `console.log(val)` but not from `console.log(val.counter)`? If so, then your `if` statement never evaluates to true. If you need more help, you need to provide your HTML for the button elements.

Comment: Note that you can simplify your code significantly, if you use the button's id as the key to your object. You can replace your entire `forEach()` with just `orders[e.target.id].counter++;`.

Comment: I watched the first solution and it solved it for me, but somehow it got removed. basically, I changed my order objects: key is the id, value is the counter. I removed the forEach and just added orders[e.target.id] ++;